# Return variable from script?

Tags: python, variables, output

I´m trying to get access to a variable from a python script to the command lines.

I run following command line with several args:

```
!python test.py --model I3D_resnet50 --dataset kinetics400
```

In this `test.py` there is variable `Test1`.
If I use `sys.exit(Test1)` in `test.py` there will be just the value printed in the command line, but I need the value saved in a variable.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is easier to `import` that module (`test`) from your code and call the function that (hopefully) return that value instead of running it on the command line. It depends on how `test.py` is written.

Comment: Just write the value with `print`, rather than `sys.exit` (which will make your script appear to have failed). `!python` suggests you are running your command from a Jupyter notebook; I am not sure how to capture the output in that environment. (From the shell, you would write `x=$(python test.py python test.py --model I3D_resnet50 --dataset kinetics400)`.

Comment: Thanks chepner, worked with this solution.
`x=!(python test.py  --model I3D_resnet50 --dataset kinetics400)`
`variable=x[-1]`
`print(variable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your shell. With *nix, you can do something like

test.py

```
var = 'Something'
print (var)
```

and then in the shell

```
x=$(python test.py)
```

x will be whatever went to stdout. In this case,

```
echo $x
Something
```

If your in Windows, you'll need something like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120731-00/?p=7003).

Comment: `!python ...` suggests the OP is running their script from inside a Jupyter notebook, or at least some other non-shell environment.

Comment: yes running the script on Google Colab, but thanks Wyrmwood, your explanation helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways, but most will run a subshell, so you won't have access to the environment variables in the shell you're running the script from.

Did you just want to see what a variable is? In that case, you can use

```
import os
os.system('echo '+var_of_interest)
```